# Composer not installing on windows machine

Tags: php, laravel, apache, xampp, composer-php

I am very new to web development and mostly following tutorials so, I am learning laravel and I want to install composer. I downloaded the setup from the composer website and manually added the PHP path in environment variable I am using xampp. when I run the installer I get this error

"The Composer installer script did not run correctly because composer.phar was not downloaded."

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcatg.png)

Comment: Can you please try to re-download the setup and run it as administrator

Comment: running as admin worked thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways you could fix it,

1. Run the following command in the cmd:

   `php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('http://getcomposer.org/installer'));"`
2. Uninstall and then re-install and run as administrator(run the .exe if you're on windows)

The first one fixed mine once.